# Calculating Maximum filesize of inode

Tags: unix, filesystems, inode

I am trying to understand a question. I came up to a point and now I am stuck. Please help me with this.

Question was

The block size of an i-node based file system is 'b' bytes. There are 'q' direct pointers to data block and one indirect pointer in the i-node. Each pointer is 'p' bits in length. It is given that q < 2^p < (b*8)/p. What is the size of the largest file that can be handled by the file system?

This was my approach

```
size of the direct pointed blocks = q*b

max pointers in a block = 8*b/p

size of the blocks pointed by indirect pointer = 8*b*b/p

So the largest file = qb + 8*b*b*/p
```

I am confused how to use the given fact ** q < 2^p < (b*8)/p ** in the answer.

Can anyone help me please?